# CSS-transition equal to SlideToggle animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

With the code below a `<panel>` is displayed once the user hovers over the `<button>`. This all works fine. However, I am not satisified with the animation of the `<panel>`.

For me the `<panel>` slides in like an "accordion" but I would prefer an animation where the panel is **revealed** by a "going down bottom line" similar to a **slideToggle animation** of **jQuery**.

Is that even possible with **CSS** and if yes what do I have to change in my code to make this animation work?

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/16/)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  height: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.button_name {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button:hover .panel {
  height: 80%;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0%;
  transition: height 0.5s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.panel div {
  height: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">

  <div class="button_name">Menu</div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
    <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
    <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
    <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the animation to be applied individually to each menu item, or the entire panel in general?

Comment: It's happening because `.panel div {height: 25%;}` continuously changing it's height to become `25%` of it's parent during animation.

Comment: @Terry: The entire panel in general.

Comment: @Abshishek: So it is never possible to have such an animation with a relative height (%)?

Comment: No, even if you use `slideToggle` it will give the same results I guess. It's a basic nature of element.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/simplysam/kvz4m6pb/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Abshishek: How could you solve this issue. I put the 25% to ensure that the 4 items fit exactly into their surrounding parent. Is there another way to ensure the fitting of those items into their parent and having the animation working the way I wanted it? I tried to go with display: flex but could not make it work yet: https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite simple: by changing the height you are causing the height of individual menu items to collapse. Since CSS lays things out from top to bottom, that means that when the height is not sufficient to fit the content, the bottom will be cut off and not the top (the latter which is an effect you want).

A solution will be to:

1. Use constant height, and then
2. Use CSS transformation to slide up/down the panel contents

You simply translate it along the y/vertical axis by its own height (`transform: translateY('-100%')`) at the beginning, and change that value to `0%` on hover:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  height: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  
  /* Hide panel content that are translated out of parent bounding box */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button_name {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
  
  /* Set position to relative so it stays above panel content */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button:hover .panel {
  /* Slide the panel down */
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80%;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
  
  /* Slide the panel up */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.panel div {
  height: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">

  <div class="button_name">Menu</div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div> 1.0 Menu </div>
    <div> 2.0 Menu </div>
    <div> 3.0 Menu </div>
    <div> 4.0 Menu </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks a lot for your answer. I also uptaded it here https://jsfiddle.net/kyva8mhe/23/